# What is 3-dimensional toroidal?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology

Picture below is from Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow. I don't know what is the 3-dimensional toroidal. Is it
$$
 T^3 = S^1\times S^1 \times S^1   ~~~~?
$$
Besides, how to construct a metric on it such that the sectional curvature is $-1$ ?

> [image]

Comment: It says a "toroidal end", and as the picture shows, a toroidal end is given by $T^2 \times (0,\infty)$, where $T^2. = S^1 \times S^1$ is the $2$-dimensional torus. Using coordinates $(x,y) \in S^1\times S^1$ and $t \in (0,\infty)$, the metric $$g = dt^2 + e^{-2t}(dx^2 + dy^2)$$ has sectional curvature $-1$. This is equivalent to starting with the half space model of hyperbolic space, $(0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^2$ with metric $dt^2 + e^{-2t}(dx^2+dy^2)$, and taking its quotient by the horizontal $\mathbb{Z}^2$ action of isometries.

Comment: "Toroidal" is not a noun. It is an adjective, a property of an [end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)) of a hyperbolic three-manifold.

Comment: @Deane  Thanks, let me calculate it.

Comment: @LeeMosher  Haha, I learn some English, Thanks.